# okhttp3 OkHttpClient setWriteTimeout equivalent

Tags: spring-boot, okhttp

I'm converting the okhttp.OkHttpClient.setWriteTimeout to okhttp3.OkHttpClient.setWriteTimeout but I'm getting undefined error even with okhttp3.OkHttpClient.writeTimeout.

It's weird, but writeTimeout is in the documentation,
https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/OkHttpClient.Builder.html#Builder--

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[writeTimeout()](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/OkHttpClient.Builder.html#writeTimeout-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) is part of `okhttp3.OkHttpClient.Builder`, not `okhttp3.OkHttpClient`. We could set the writeTimeout, along with proxy and any other configurations, with a single builder:

```java
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .proxy(proxy)
        .writeTimeout(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .readTimeout(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .build();
```

Comment: you should create a youtube, I'll donate to you right away.  Thanks and more power.

Comment: @Rickytik Thanks! Currently I am not allowed to make profit from YouTube due to my visa status. I'd like to create a YouTube channel once I am eligible. Anyway, I am really glad I could help!